# I am having difficulty getting a new version of a 3rd party SDK to import into Android Studio

Tags: string, import, android-studio, resources

I am having difficulty getting a new version of a 3rd party SDK to import into Android Studio.

In the earlier version they released .jar and .so files which I copied into /lib and /jniLibs and then added the lib files into the Android Studio app and everything worked.  The app ran, used the libraries and all was good in the world.  Recently a new version of this SDK was released but in this new release they have resource files (but they are not compiled into the jar/so files; there is a $Rstring.class files that they say I should import.  I've now spent days copying into various locations in the app project with no luck and the missing strings result in crashes when calling their SDK.

OK, I figure I'd try to import their SDK folder (which is how they document to do it if you are using Eclipse).  Well, no matter what I've tried and after selecting the folder or SDK's project file I get a dialog asking for the Eclipse workspace and a list of what appears to be source file names.  I can't get past this dialog because obviously I don't have their files.

Has anyone run into this and found a solution; perhaps I'm missing something in the process but after spending the better part of 3-4 days trying and searching and trying more things I'm hopeful for help from the community.

Comment: File > Import Module doesn't work?

Comment: As indicated in my original comments; I tried using import but get errors that it needs the project files (and gives me file names that appear to be C code files).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer and it was a combination of issues in how this particular 3rd party distributed the SDK and not fully understanding the menu.

The 3rd party in question packaged the SDK with the output files of the build as well as files that needed to be imported making an import alone to not work.

Combine this with menu confusion: File->Import Module is NOT the same as New->Modules->Import Existing Project only added to the confusion.

The solution ended up being to use the File->Import Module which appears to be a very different operation and once done *most* of the issues where solved.  It solved the main issues I asked above which was missing resourced.

Still missing was the library (.jar) files which had to me copied into the app's lib folder and "added as library" but the .SO files did not need to be copied and in fact doing that resulted in a duplicate files warning.

I'm not sure I can fully explain what happened but what I think happened is that the "module" was where the app read the .so and string resources from but was unable to load the .jar files because (I suspect) these files where not part of the module but rather where outputs of building the source and it was removing the source files which caused the inability of the new->Module->Import to fail.

Hopefully this makes sense or at least give someone an idea of what to look for when/if they run into a similar issue.